# Add delay to While loop for animation to complete

Tags: android

The SwipeSample I'm using has an animation xml that slides the layouts for left to right etc. There is a duration set to 800 on each of the animations.

I have a while loop that checks what position the user clicks on and then loops the animation to complete the loop.

What I'm finding is that if I'm at current position of 1 and I want to go to 0 the animation works fine. If I'm at position 6 and want to go to 0 the layouts seems to slide over in one hit the loop does not allow the animation time to play before each pass.

Is it possible to add a delay to a while loop or should I be using another approach?

This is the code:

case R.id.EditTYellow:
            System.out.println("Text Yellow pressed");

```
        if(viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild()!=0 || viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild()> 0 ){
            do  
             { 
            viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
            viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            //Delay need here to allow animation to complete
             } while (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild()!=0);
        }                       
        //System.out.println("New Flipper "+viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild());
    break;
```

I've tried adding a Thread.sleep(800) but it did not seem to work.

```
            try {
                Thread.sleep(800);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thread.sleep is EVIL. Using it to fix synchronization issues is a big no no. Animations in android can let you know when they're done... through the AnimationListener callback. You set the listener into your animation (slideRightIn, slideRightOut) and the animation itself will tell you when it's done, after which you can do whatever you want.

```
slideRightIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
      // will be called when your animation is complete 
    }
});
```